# 'You may use an unstructured form for text so that you can tag it with...'

Tags: discourse-context

This is from [one of “For Dummies” series](https://www.dummies.com/book/technology/information-technology/ai/general-ai/artificial-intelligence-for-dummies-281623/).

> You can view data as being one of two types, structured and
> unstructured, depending on how you produce and consume it....
>
> Typical examples of structured data are database tables,...
>
> Unstructured data consists of images, videos, and sound recordings.
> **You may use an unstructured form for text**  so that you can tag it with characteristics, such as size, date, or content type.

I think it is better to rewrite the phrase in bold like '*You may use text for an unstructured form*'.

Am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong. The original wording means that if you've got some "data" that's in text format, you can choose to record/store it as "unstructured data". Your rephrasing would mean that if you had some data that was in an "unstructured form", you could choose to store it as text - if indeed that means anything at all. The confusion arises because the cited original loosely uses the word "text" to mean "data which is in text format".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I clearly understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not. (I would have to see much more context from the book to be sure.)

> You may use an unstructured form for text

says that when you have data that happens to be text you need not structure it.

Your suggested replacement

> You may use text for an unstructured form

seems to me to say that you can describe (using text) some unstructured data.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.